# Android Kernel) Cannot find Image.lz4-dtb file after building the android kernel

Tags: android-kernel

I need to modify the android's kernel so I follow the instruction from this

https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building-kernels?hl=ko#customize-build

But after sync the kernel's repo and building it,
I can't find the 'Image.lz4-dtb' file from output folder
Only Image and Image.lz4 file exist

I download the 'common-android13-5.10' kernel and build it with following command

> BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.gki.aarch64 build/build.sh

I also did it with bazel tool with following command too

> tools/bazel build //common:kernel_aarch64_dist

Is there any way to make Image.lz4-dtb?

Or is it same with Image.lz4 and Image.lz4-dtb?
If so, Image.lz4 is not working with

> fastboot boot Image.lz4-dtb

this commands. in 'fastboot boot Image.lz4', it shows "Unrecognized command" error.